# Unchecked Cast warning - shows up for Type parameters but not for Concrete types?

Tags: java, generics, jls, unchecked, unchecked-cast

Consider the following snippet:

```java
        Integer a = Integer.valueOf(23);
        Double d = (Double) (Number) a; //not unchecked cast


        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> integerList = (List<Integer>)(List<?>)stringList; //unchecked cast
```

- From what I understand - whenever we convert `Supertype -> Subtype` **Unchecked cast is flagged as the compiler does not know until the runtime if the type represented by the `Supertype` will ever match the `SubType`.**
- Then over here - why is `(Double) (Number)a` not being flagged as the `Unchecked Cast`?

Comment: "he compiler does not know until the runtime" <-- Incorrect. Not even the runtime knows at the point of the cast. If the cast is invalid, it will be known _later_, or even never at all.

Comment: @Sweeper : I mean the same thing - that until runtime the java system will not know if the cast will be compatible or not - if it does not then it will be flagged as the RuntimeException.

Comment: @user16320675 : yeah .. that's true - then how do you define "Unchecked" cast?

Comment: @user16320675 : Ok - then how about this : `Integer a = Integer.valueOf(23);Class dd = (Class) (Object) a; //not unchecked cast`

Comment: @user16320675 : Or rather the example that I pasted above - do u mean that the runtime will happily allow the `List<String> -> List<?> -> List<Integer>` at runtime?

Comment: @theutonium.18 Yes. Did you not even run your code?

Comment: @user16320675 : sounds good as sweeper also mentioned - but will wait for some more comments on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unchecked cast is flagged as the compiler does not know until the runtime if the type represented by the `Supertype` will ever match the `SubType`.

That is incorrect. Not even the runtime knows whether your list is a `ArrayList<String>` or a `ArrayList<Integer>`. As far as the runtime is concerned, your list is an `ArrayList` (This is because of [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)). This is why casting a `List<?>` to a `List<String>` cannot be checked by the runtime. The runtime does not know what a `List<String>` is - it only knows about `List`. To the runtime, no checks are needed, since you are just casting from `List` to `List`, which always succeeds. In fact, nothing is done for this cast at runtime - it is a *completely unchecked* cast.

As a result, this code runs without throwing an exception:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
stringList.add("foo");
List<Integer> integerList = (List<Integer>)(List<?>)stringList;
System.out.println(integerList.size());
```

It *will* throw an exception, however, if you did:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
stringList.add("foo");
List<Integer> integerList = (List<Integer>)(List<?>)stringList;
System.out.println(integerList.get(0) - 1);
```

Now, you are getting an integer out of the list, and doing some integer-specific operations to it. But the list contains `"foo"`, which isn't an integer. The compiler inserts an implicit cast to cast `integerList.get(0)` to `Integer`, and that cast failed. Note that this is a checked cast, because the runtime knows about the type `Integer`.

The cast from `Number` to `Double` is also checked, because the runtime knows about `Double`.

Side note: there are also "partially unchecked casts", which are things like casting from `Object` to `ArrayList<String>`. The runtime can check whether the `Object` is an `ArrayList`, but it cannot check whether it is an array list of **strings**.

See all the rules for what is checked and what is unchecked [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.2).